# Executing an ELF in Linux kernel with workqueue or kthread

Tags: c, linux-kernel, elf

I'm trying to start a userspace process (execute an ELF binary) inside the kernel when receiving a network message. In the network event handler, I initiate a work queue. In the workqueue handling function, I call `do_execve` but there comes a kernel panic with:

```
[  113.305996] Unable to handle kernel paging request at virtual address ffffffffffffffd8
[  113.306375] pgd = ffff8000f9d06000
[  113.306520] [ffffffffffffffd8] *pgd=0000000000000000
[  113.306915] Internal error: Oops: 96000004 [#1] SMP
```

The code:

```
static void clone_thread(struct work_struct *_work)
{
        struct pcn_kmsg_work *work = (struct pcn_kmsg_work *)_work;
        network_request_t *req = work->msg;
        int ret = 0;

        PSPRINTK("%s: exe_path %s\n", __func__, req->exe_path);
        ret = do_execve(getname_kernel(req->exe_path), NULL, NULL);
        PSPRINTK("%s: filename %p\n", __func__, getname_kernel(req->exe_path));
        PSPRINTK("%s: ret %d\n", __func__, ret);
}

static int handle_network_request(struct pcn_kmsg_message *msg)
{
        network_request_t *req = (network_request_t *)msg;
        struct pcn_kmsg_work *work = kmalloc(sizeof(*work), GFP_ATOMIC);
        BUG_ON(!work);

        work->msg = req;
        INIT_WORK((struct work_struct *)work, clone_thread);
        queue_work(pcn_wq, (struct work_struct *)work);

        return 0;
}
... ...
```

Then I tried to call `do_execve` in a kernel thread. But for some reason, the kernel thread only executes the `printk` never execute `do_execve`.

So I'm wondering how can I execute the ELF inside Linux kernel? Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use the `call_usermodehelper()` internal kernel API for this:

```
#include <linux/kmod.h>

/* ... */ 

{
    char ∗argv[] = { req->exe_path, NULL };
    static char ∗envp[] = {
        "HOME=/",
        "TERM=linux",
        "PATH=/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin", NULL };

    return call_usermodehelper( argv[0], argv, envp, UMH_WAIT_EXEC );
}
```

It also looks to me like your `struct pcn_kmsg_message` is likely freed before the work queue runs - you probably need to copy the `exe_path` string into the `pcn_kmsg_work` structure, instead of just copying the pointer.

Comment: It works when I replace `do_execve` with the code you provided. But I don't think the kernel panic is caused by `req->exe_path` is freed. I used it in `call_usermodehelper`, it works fine. I also replaced `req->exe_path` with a string and `do_execve`, it also faults. I guess there may be something wrong when executing `do_execve` in a work queue.

Comment: Yes, `do_execve()` replaces the current thread with the newly executed one so you definitely don't want to do that from a workqueue anyway.